# remove first 3 columns from a .htb file

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I have a .htb file which I want to edit with python so I can later import the values to a MySQL table. The MySQL table has the Descriptions as column names.

The .htb file consists of 4 columns and I want to remove the first 3 (Description, Shortdescription, Unit) so that I only have the values left.
This is how the .htb file looks:

```
Description\tShortdescription\tUnit\tValue\n
\n
Hub\tHub\tmm\t68.000000000000\t\t\t\n           
Bohrung\tBohru\tmm\t89.000000000000\t\t\t\n
-----\n
Rechenbeginn\tKW_Start\t°KW\t-117.648988767436\t\t\t\n
```

To be able to import the the values to MySQL I also have to remove:

1. "-----"
2. The column names and the blank line "Description\tShortdescription\tUnit\tValue\n
   \n"
3. the \t\t\t

which I have already managed by doing this:

```
 with open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Werte.htb", "r") as infile, \
 open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Werte Aufbereitet.htb", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
 data = infile.read():
 data = data.replace("Description   Shortdescription    Unit    Value\n", "")
 data = data.replace("\n", "")
 data = data.replace("-----", "")
 data = data.replace("\t\t\t", "\n")
 outfile.write(data)
```

my question now is how do I remove the first 3 columns? The best way my final file would look like is this:

```
68.000000000000\n
89.000000000000\n
-117.648988767436\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the file line by line and append the processed data to a single string and write it back to the file.

```
with open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Werte.htb", "r") as infile, 
open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Werte Aufbereitet.htb", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    data = infile.read():
    data = data.replace("Description  Shortdescription    Unit    Value\n", "")
    data = data.replace("\n", "")
    data = data.replace("-----", "")
    data = data.replace("\t\t\t", "\n")
    final_data = ""
    for line in data.split("\n")[:-1]:
         final_data += line.split("\t")[3] // choosing 4th value
         final_data += "\n"
    outfile.write(final_data)
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help, i get the error: list index out of range in line final_data += line.split("\t")[3]. I havent figured out why im getting this error

Comment: Does your .htb file always contain the 4th column?

Comment: That's the problem the last line doesn't contain 4 columns because we remove \t\t\t and replace it with \n there is one blank line in the end of the file.

Comment: You can update the loop to 
for line in data.split("\n")[:-1]

Comment: i have one more question. what do i have to change in the code if i dont want a \n in the last row?